# WebRequest and data from label

Tags: c#

I created the authorization on PHP-MySql and it works fine. All spoil the TextBox I think. This is my PHP code. No errors in it.

```
<?php
include('../functions.php'); // connect mysqli
if ($_POST['form_name'] == 'loginform') {
  $crypt_pass = md5($_POST['password']);
  $found = false;

  $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE username = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'");
  if ($data = $res->fetch_array()) {
    if ($crypt_pass == $data['password']) {
      $found = true;
    }
  }
  if ($found == false) {
    echo 'LoginFail';
  }
  else {
    echo 'LoginOK';
  }
}
?>
```

And my WebRequest:

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://unknow.com/user/login2.php");
 request.Method = "POST";
 string postData = "form_name=loginform&username=" + LoginInput + 
      "&password=" + PasswordInput;
 byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
 Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
 dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
 dataStream.Close();
 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
 dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
 string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
 Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
 response_label.Text = responseFromServer;
 reader.Close();
 dataStream.Close();
 response.Close();
```

When this code all right, PHP tell me "LoginOK":

```
string postData="form_name=loginform&username=snosme&password=123456";
```

But when code:

```
string postData = "form_name=loginform&username=" + LoginInput + 
      "&password=" + PasswordInput;
```

PHP tell me LoginFail. Although I enter the same data in the TextBox. What's the problem?

Comment: How is Ukraine this evening? :)

Comment: Good thing you didn't post the real URL because apparently you are using an MD5 hash to "encrypt" a password. Fail. Not to mention that you are posting the values in the url instead of the request body...

Comment: Where are LoginInput and PasswordInput coming from? Are they text fields or the actual text in the text fields?

Comment: image http://s6.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2013/08/2555abb3584ea8ad9bf6865fcc294e0c.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your image, I think the problem is that you are forgetting to get the Text value in the text field. Try this:

```
string postData = "form_name=loginform&username=" + LoginInput.Text + 
  "&password=" + PasswordInput.Text;
```